# Firebase console TPS handling of push notification

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I have 1 million user base, so if I'm sending push notification through firebase console my active users get increases drastically which causing some trouble at server end for few time. So I have two questions regarding that -

1. What is the transaction limit(TPS) of firebase for sending notification.
2. Can I tune transaction limit(TPS) of firebase console according to my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any limit to sending notifications with FCM. Although if you are using topics, and you're sending too many messages at a time to a single topic, you might receive the [Topics Message Rate Exceeded](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) error from time to time, in which case you could just implement an exponential backoff.

So to answer your questions:

1. There isn't any.
2. I'm not sure what you mean by this. The console contains the data about your Firebase project and some features related to interacting with your app (like the Notifications Console), that's about what it could do.

Comment: You didn’t get my point, Suppose I’m sending push to 1 million users from firebase console then how much time farebase will take in delivery to all user base

Comment: And can I configure firebase to send push notifications to 100 users in 1 second (100 TPS)

Comment: Looks like you're not familiar with the Firebase Console nor with FCM. You cant *just* send a million messages via the console. At most you get to send to 1000 each message. But that would take a while, you're gonna have to use the API. The message is sent almost immediately to the clients, provided that they are connected to a stable internet connection and that there are no restrictions on the device itself. In general, the delivery time varies per device. There is no option or settings to set anything like that for FCM.